# Return error to client from Jersey's parameter injection code?

Tags: java, rest, dependency-injection, jersey-2.0

I have a couple of custom parameters that get injected into REST method handlers using Jersey 2.9. The parameter injection is performed by extending Jersey's `AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory` and related classes, as such:

@Provider
public class ParamProviderFactory extends AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory {

```
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;

@Override
public Object provide() {
    // do some work, error happened due to user giving wrong query string format

    // IMPORTANT PART:
    // I need to return an error to the user from here

    return result;
}
```

}

The parameter value injected depends on Query strings given by the user. If the query string values are invalid, I need to return an error to the user.

The question is: How can I return an error to the user and abort the REST call handling from within the `provide` method?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following in the provide() method:

```
getContainerRequest().abortWith(yourResponse)
```